# Foreach through an array without looping

Tags: php

In the following code:

```
<?php
    foreach($this->params as $key=>$val)
    {
      $this->rawRequest .= "&$key=$val";
    }
?>
```

How would you get `$this->params` as a `$key=>$val` without looping?

Comment: Try http_build_query http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

Comment: There is more than one key and value in `params`. What do you want to happen if you avoid a loop?

Comment: Please be clear about your expected inputs and outputs. See http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

i agree with @rjdown
the simplest way to create a query string based on any array keys and values is
http_build_query

```
$buildQString = http_build_query($this->params);
```

Comment: And that is the reason to post it as an answer to collect rep. Instead of just   commenting or just doing +1?